# Confused by Runge-Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, runge-kutta-methods

I need to solve flight of the shell problem (get XY trajectory using Runge-Kutta method) and at first check if method works on some simple test system.

So here's  Runge-Kutta stuff

$k_1 = f(t_n, y_n)$

$k_2 = f(t_n + h/2, y_n + hk_1/2) $

$k_3 = f(t_n+h, y_n - hk_1 + 2hk_2)$

$y_{n+1} = y_n + h(k_1 + 4k_2 + k_3)/6$

where $h$ is step

Here's my test system

$y'_1 = -5y_1 - 10y_2 + 14e^{-x}$

$y'_2 = -10y_1 - 5y_2 + 14e^{-x}$

approximately it's  $y1 = y2 = e^{-x}$

So I solve it on $[0;4]$ and checked it (by comparison with  $y1 = y2 = e^{-x}$) (btw approximation is very good even with h=0.1). Here's the matlab code, if you interested in

Rnge-Kutta method

```
  function [ res_y ] = RungeKutta(dim, size, grid, step, f1,f2,y1, y2)

    k1=zeros(dim);
    k2=zeros(dim);
    k3=zeros(dim);

    h = step;

    res_y(1,1) = y1;
    res_y(2,1) = y2;

    for i=1: size

       k1(1)= f1(grid(i),y1,y2);
       k1(2)= f2(grid(i),y1,y2);

       k2(1)= f1(grid(i)+h/2, y1+h*k1(1)/2, y2+h*k1(2)/2);
       k2(2)= f2(grid(i)+h/2, y1+h*k1(1)/2, y2+h*k1(2)/2);

       k3(1)= f1(grid(i)+h, y1-h*k1(1)+2*h*k2(1), y2-h*k1(2)+2*h*k2(2));
       k3(2)= f2(grid(i)+h, y1-h*k1(1)+2*h*k2(1), y2-h*k1(2)+2*h*k2(2));

       res_y(1,i+1) = y1 + h*(k1(1) + 4*k2(1) + k3(1))/6;
       res_y(2,i+1) = y1 + h*(k1(2) + 4*k2(2) + k3(2))/6;

       y1 = res_y(1,i+1); 
       y2 = res_y(2,i+1);
    end

 end
```

Main method

```
a = 0; b = 4;
h = 0.1; % step
t = a:h:b; %grid
n = 2; 
m = size(t,2);


 hold on;
     plot(t, exp(-t),'b-')
     plot(t, exp(-t),'r--')
 hold off;

y1=1; y2 = 1;

f1_ptr = @f1;% out = -5 * y1 - 10 * y2 + (14)*exp(-x);
f2_ptr = @f2;% out = -10 * y1 - 5 * y2 + (14)*exp(-x);

res_y = RungeKutta(n,m-1,t,h,f1_ptr, f2_ptr,1,1);

hold on;
plot(t,res_y);

hold off;
```

f1 function

```
function [ out ] = f1( x, y1, y2, alpha, beta )
if nargin == 3
    alpha = 5;
    beta = 10;
end

out = -alpha * y1 - beta * y2 + (alpha + beta - 1)*exp(-x);

end
```

f2 function

```
function [ out ] = f2( x, y1, y2, alpha, beta )
if nargin == 3
    alpha = 5;
    beta = 10;
end
out = -beta * y1 - alpha * y2 + (alpha + beta - 1)*exp(-x);

end
```

But my main system, for the shell trajectory look like that

$x'' = - \frac{1}{2m} C \rho S \cos(\theta) v^2$

$y'' = - \frac{1}{2m} C \rho S \sin(\theta) v^2 - g$

Where's $v = \sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2}$ and angle $\theta = arctg(y'/x')$ and $C, \rho, S, m, g$ some constants.

Also I've got some initial conditions

$x(0) = 0, y(0) = 0, \theta(0) = 0.6, v(0) = 50 m/s$

So I've stuck here. I don't understand clearly how to solve this system using Runge-Kutta method. I mean, I don't understand how to code it in such situation.

I'm not good at math, I am a coder. Please, colud you help me?

**UPD**
Thanks to Tony I think I began to understand problem. But method I wrote doesn't work :c

Here it is

```
function [ shell_result ] = RungeKuttaShell(step, y1,y2,y3,y4)

    h = step; norma = 1;
    i = 1;
    shell_result(1,1) = y1;
    shell_result(2,1) = y2;
    shell_result(3,1) = y3;
    shell_result(4,1) = y4;

    while (norma > 0) %how much iterations?

       k1(1)= fz(y3);
       k1(2)= fw(y4);
       k1(3)=fx(k1(1), k1(2));
       k1(4)=fy(k1(1), k1(2));

       k2(1)= fz( y3+h*k1(1)/2);
       k2(2)= fw( y4+h*k1(2)/2);
       k2(3)=fx(k2(1),k2(2));
       k2(4)=fy(k2(1),k2(2));

       k3(1)= fz(y3-h*k1(1)+2*h*k2(1));
       k3(2)= fw(y4-h*k1(2)+2*h*k2(2));
       k3(3)=fx(k3(1),k3(2));
       k3(4)=fy(k3(1),k3(2));

       shell_result(1,i+1) = y1 + h*(k1(1) + 4*k2(1) + k3(1))/6;
       shell_result(2,i+1) = y2 + h*(k1(2) + 4*k2(2) + k3(2))/6;
       shell_result(3,i+1) = y3 + h*(k1(3) + 4*k2(3) + k3(3))/6;
       shell_result(4,i+1) = y4 + h*(k1(4) + 4*k2(4) + k3(4))/6;

       y1 = shell_result(1,i+1); 
       y2 = shell_result(2,i+1);
       y3 = shell_result(3,i+1); 
       y4 = shell_result(4,i+1);
       i = i+1;
       norma = y4; %height?
    end

end
```

functions look like this

```
function [ output ] = fx( z,w)
    m=15; C=0.2; rho=1.29; S=0.25; g = 9.81;

        output = -((1/2*m)*C*rho*S)*z*sqrt(z*z + w*w);

end

function [ output ] = fy( z,w )
    m=15; C=0.2; rho=1.29; S=0.25; g = 9.81;

    output = -((1/2*m)*C*rho*S)*w*sqrt(z*z + w*w) - g;

end

function [ output_args ] = fw( input_args )

    output_args = input_args;

end

function [ output_args ] = fz( input_args )

     output_args = input_args;

end
```

And I use it just like that

```
shell = RungeKuttaShell(0.1,0,0,v0*cos(th0), v0*sin(th0));
```

Comment: I'll take a detailed look at this code after lunch. But one passing note, `zeros(dim)` generates a square matrix of dimensions `dim` by `dim`. If you want to create a column vector, you should use `zeros(dim,1)`.

Comment: I'm looking at your code, and your Runge-Kutta method does not work. It is not clear from your question or your code what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @Arkamis what do you mean by does not work? oh, maybe it's because of function pointers! I'll update the post

Comment: @Arkamis it works for the test system, it does approximately execute $e^{-x}$ function!

I need to solve flight of the shell(or bullet, whatever) where the system is with double derivative system. But I don't even know how to start

Comment: Do you know how to decompose a second-order ODE into a system of first-order equations?

Comment: @Arkamis well, yeah. I guess there will be system with 4 equations. Wait I'll try to write it

Comment: @Arkamis does it looks like that?
$x' = z$ ;
$y' = w$ ;
$z' = - \frac{1}{2m} C \rho S \cos(\theta) v^2$ ;

$w' = - \frac{1}{2m} C \rho S \sin(\theta) v^2 - g$

Comment: @DanilGholstman Use vector notation, rather than individually naming all the variables. Your independent variable is $\mathbf{y}$, and your dependent variable is $\mathbf{x}$. MATLAB allows you to write vector-valued functions, so you can reduce your code quite a bit and improve its readability.

Comment: $v^2=z^2+w^2\,$ of course.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo oh, and the angle $\theta = arctg(\frac{w}{z})$ ?

Comment: You need $\cos\theta=z/v \;$ and $\; \sin\theta=w/v\,$.$\;$ So ...

Comment: @TonyPiccolo well, don't underastand how it helps me to solve main system using RungeKutta, sorry

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain better ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo sorry, my english is not good Well, what I trying to do is solve main equations system (include this $x'' = - \frac{1}{2m} C \rho S \cos(\theta) v^2$ and this 
$y'' = - \frac{1}{2m} C \rho S \sin(\theta) v^2 - g$) using RungeKutta method. I solve the test system, but equations there were simple, here I don't understand what to do or how to change my code for the main equations system

Comment: I think it is better I give you an answer: please wait ...

Comment: Is $y4$ the height ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo well, there is $g$ in `fy` function, so I thought it suppose to output height

Comment: Write norma = y2 instead of norma = y4 and 1/2/m instead of 1/2*m. Choose 1.7 for step. With those initial values the range is 176 m in 5.3 s. Probably the trajectory is obtained by plot(shell(1,:),shell(2,:)).

Comment: @TonyPiccolo oh, sorry I've been busy last days.I'll try it today at home! (I'm on my job right now until 6:00 pm(now it's like 9 am here)).  And by the way is step value is so important? I mean if I choose step = 0.1 is there things would be a lot different? Cuz it shouldn't actually

Comment: See my **Edit**.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo oh, btw range I got is 185m ._.

Comment: Too much divergence. If you want, I check your program.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo, well if u want to. My step value is `0.1`. And btw actually correct value with such parameters, as I got is `182m`  (i asked teacher about it).
Also, I didn't used your code from `edit` part - only changed `norma` and this `1/2/m`

Comment: @Arkamis oh, sir, and thank you too!

Comment: Surely I want. The step is not so important, I suspect instead that the code in my edit is the right one. Can you try it ? Only k2 and k3 have to be substituted.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo well, I edited it and thats what I get http://i.imgur.com/Paphuan.png

And this is what I got before http://i.imgur.com/pYlR2Hl.png

Comment: My first code was wrong: try my **final code**.

Comment: At the end, if all is well, it should be fine to plot the resistive trajectory together with the unresistive one (C=0) in a uniform scale.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo yep, now I got same values as you! but how did you found what is correct?

Comment: I use Maple technology: one cannot be wrong !

Comment: @TonyPiccolo well, yesterday I shown results to the teacher. And she said that it's wrong! There were a few reasons. Well, I guess I will start new question tomorrow or today ._.

Comment: Let me know the reasons if possible.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I posted new question! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system is $$\begin {cases} x'=z \\ \\y'=w \\ \\ z'=-k\,z\sqrt{z^2+w^2} \\ \\w'=-k\,w\sqrt{z^2+w^2}-g \end {cases}$$with$$k=\frac 1{2m}C\rho S$$The initial values are $x(0)=0\;,\; y(0)=0\;,\;z(0)=v(0)\cos\theta(0)\;,\;w(0)=v(0)\sin\theta(0)\,$.

You must be clever in recoding your procedure.
The system now is $$\begin {cases} y'_1=f_1(t,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4) \\ \\y'_2=f_2(t,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4) \\ \\ y'_3=f_3(t,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4) \\ \\y'_4=f_4(t,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4) \end {cases}$$The previous one was$$\begin {cases} y'_1=f_1(t,y_1,y_2) \\ \\y'_2=f_2(t,y_1,y_2) \end {cases}$$You must recode *completely* without any reference to your particular system (this only conditions the choice of the functions).

Now $y_1=x\;$,$\;y_2=y\;$,$\;y_3=z\;$,$\;y_4=w$.

**Edit**

The choice of step value is not so important if one is not interested in saving resources (of time and space of memory). Do the changes in my comment and try.

If you don't get a range of 176 m, try this

**final code**

k2(1)= fz( y3+h*k1(3)/2);
k2(2)= fw( y4+h*k1(4)/2);
k2(3)=fx(k2(1),k2(2));
k2(4)=fy(k2(1),k2(2));

k3(1)= fz(y3-h*k1(3)+2*h*k2(3));
k3(2)= fw(y4-h*k1(4)+2*h*k2(4));
k3(3)=fx(k3(1),k3(2));
k3(4)=fy(k3(1),k3(2));

Comment: ah, i guess I started to get it!
but how I suppose to recode in that way? I mean in my test system $f_1 $ and $f_2$ equations were use $y_1$ and $y_2$ parameters, thats why I made it like $y'_1 = f_1(t, y_1, y_2)$

Comment: and by the way is there 5 parameters necessery in the main system? I mean in main system there are no any correlation with $t$, isn't it depends on $w$ and $z$ only(or $y_3, y_4$)?

Comment: _For personal use_ you can write a simpler code related to the particular system but there is some risk: edit your question and I'll check it.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by edit question?

Comment: I mean you add the code to your question.

Comment: Code for what? I mean there is already code of RungeKutta method

Comment: You need a code for a 4x4 system (4 equations, 4 unknowns) for the same method (Runge-Kutta) of course. Your original code works with a 2x2 system.

Comment: oh, well, I'll try! That was the problem btw, but now I understood some things! I knida busy right now (i'm on my job) so sorry, but it would take some time.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.usna.edu/Users/mecheng/ratcliff/EM375info/labs/07Project/ProjectileTheory.pdf) and you are done.

Comment: I still don't understand :c And I shouldn't use ode45, I need to write my own method. What suppose to return all this $z,w,x,y$ functions? I'll update my question btw

Comment: It is matlab not c.

Comment: Well, but it looks like C or other similar language. I thought that difference here only in easy oprations with arrays and vectors. And I like plot function here too!

Comment: and isn't functions always suppose to return something?

Comment: Oh, sir, thank you very much! I get it now I think! Sorry for didn't accept answer for few days after edit - I was kinda busy.